# Node.js Testing https REST API with request module

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, https, jasmine

The jasmine unit test code with node is working for http but failed for https. How could I enable the solution for https

```
var request = require('request');
var base_url = "https://10.100.102.102/"
describe("get general info from server", function() {
  it("general info succeeded", function(done) {
    request.get(base_url + "/web_project/index.php/v1/system/generalInfo", 
      function(error, response, body) {
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
        done();
      });
  });  
});
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your URL is returning a valid response? I notice that you have a trailing slash on your base_url and a leading slash on your request url string. That may be causing the problem.

When I run the following, the test passes.

```
var request = require('request');
var base_url = "https://www.google.com/"
describe("get general info from server", function() {
  it("general info succeeded", function(done) {
    request.get(base_url, 
      function(error, response, body) {
        expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
        done();
      });
  });  
});
```

Comment: Yes, "http://10.100.102.102//web_project/index.php/v1/system/generalInfo" is working for me

Comment: Hi, to solve this issue I just need to add the ' "rejectUnauthorized": false,
' flag and the request is working. Thanks